# Selenium block requests, scripts before page loaded

Tags: selenium, http, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, blacklist

I am trying to block some requests for example; gAnalytics or gMaps and so on.  I used BrowserMobProxy before but for now, I am using the Tor network as my proxy.  Anyway, What I need to do is block some specific URLs before the driver opened or when the driver opened. I need it because the gMaps loading really takes time for my scraper.

Related topics:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415504/block-request-url-selenium-firefox-python)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295471/how-to-disable-loading-external-urls-on-seleniumlibrary-robotframework)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891301/can-i-automate-chrome-request-blocking-using-selenium-webdriver-for-ruby)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699816/url-blacklisting-with-browsermobproxy-in-robot-framework-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker/eckpjmeijpoipmldfbckahppeonkoeko?hl=en

edit and install an extension like this. This can be a solution for request blocking.